# What is the content-type of a jsp file?

Tags: javascript, json, jsp

I'm trying to set a jsp file to load but i have a doubt on it.

What is the content-type of a .jsp file?

```
application/json or application/javascript ?
```

Comment: Do you want to run that file or download it?

Comment: run that file. @rollstuhlfahrer

Comment: You mean default jsp ? `contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" `

Answer (score 2):

The default Content Type is `text/xml` see Oracle's [JSP Globalization Support](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/web.1012/b14014/jspnls.htm)

> Without any page directive settings, default settings are as follows:
>
> The default MIME type is text/html for traditional JSP pages; it is
>   text/xml for JSP XML documents.
>
> The default for the page source character encoding (for translation)
>   is ISO-8859-1 (also known as Latin-1) for traditional JSP pages; it is
>   UTF-8 or UTF-16 for JSP XML documents.
>
> The default for the response character encoding is ISO-8859-1 for
>   traditional JSP pages; it is UTF-8 or UTF-16 for JSP XML documents.

You can override it with the following attributes (specifically `contentType`):

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" 
                         pageEncoding="US-ASCII" %>
```